# Why did the mail in ballots in NY-16 tend to go to Engel?

Tags: united-states, voting, democratic-primary, vote-by-mail

Somebody asked why the late ballots tended to be Democratic in most states. The answer was that they are usually from urban areas and that they take longer to count because of population density.

However, within the Democratic Party, there was a different sort of story. In New York's 16th district, Jamaal Bowman was thought to have won 62-35 over Elliot Engel, but he ended up winning 55-41.

Another example was Carolyn Maloney in the 12th district. She lead by 1.6 points and that lead expanded to 3.7 when the votes were counted.

My belief is that those with the stronger ideology were more likely to vote in person to make sure their vote was counted. Is there any evidence for this?

Comment: Mail has traditionally been used more by older voters, who probably skewed to engel more than bowman.